# Android: Make a recorded pcm raw data playable

Tags: java, android, pcm, recording

I'm developing an Android application, which supports audio recording with the following code, sample can be found here:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do;jsessionid=tT01JrgM5DRC15pN56v20xzJXcDYv7hZVLvPhT0zJ4kfvSc1TlTM!-846162528?v=T000000090

Variables:

```
   private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
   private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 22050;
   private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS =       AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
   private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS_NUMBER = 1;
   private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
   private AudioRecord recorder = null;
   private short[] mBuffer;
   private int bufferSize = 0;
   private boolean IsRecording = false;
```

Assign a value to bufferSize:

```
 bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

Create the recorder:

```
 recorder = new AudioRecord(source, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
```

The source indicates the microphone to use.

Storing the received content in the raw file:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    DataOutputStream output = null;
    try {
    output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(getTempFilename()))));
    while (IsRecording) {
    int readSize = recorder.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
    output.writeShort(mBuffer[i]);
    } 
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
    if (output != null) {
    try {
    output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally { 
    try {
    output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }).start();
```

I would like to:

1. Play the recorded audio with android.media.MediaPlayer
2. On another activity, encode the raw source to mp3.

According to the above page I could compile the Lame library and create the wrapper. So, this raw file can be encoded to mp3 without any problems, but I can not find a way how to make this raw source playable before encoding. The found solutions for create wave header for the raw are unusable.

Has anybody have a solution for this?

Update:
For creating the headers I tried this:
...

```
in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
                        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
                        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
                int channels = 1;
                long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;
```

...
WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                                        longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

```
private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
                        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
                        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
                        long byteRate) throws IOException {
                byte[] header = new byte[44];

                header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
                header[1] = 'I';
                header[2] = 'F';
                header[3] = 'F';
                header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
                header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
                header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
                header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
                header[8] = 'W';
                header[9] = 'A';
                header[10] = 'V';
                header[11] = 'E';
                header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
                header[13] = 'm';
                header[14] = 't';
                header[15] = ' ';
                header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
                header[17] = 0;
                header[18] = 0;
                header[19] = 0;
                header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
                header[21] = 0;
                header[22] = (byte) channels;
                header[23] = 0;
                header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
                header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
                header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
                header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
                header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
                header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
                header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
                header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
                header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
                header[33] = 0;
                header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
                header[35] = 0;
                header[36] = 'd';
                header[37] = 'a';
                header[38] = 't';
                header[39] = 'a';
                header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
                header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
                header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
                header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

                out.write(header, 0, 44); 
        }
```

The result is a noisy wave file

Thank you

Comment: _"The found solutions for create wave header for the raw are unusable"_. Why? What problem(s) did you run into?

Comment: Why not use AudioTrack playback it directly?

Comment: The result was a noisy wave file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a noisy WAV, the reason could be a problem with the endian-ness of your 16-bit samples. Try swizzling the bytes around when you write them, like this:

```
int readSize = recorder.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);
for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
    output.writeShort(((mBuffer[i] >> 8) & 255) | (mBuffer[i] << 8));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this modification the np3 conversion result has the same problem, while the wave file is correct.

Comment: Good, so we have identified that endianness is the problem. Try reverting the code back to the old way (no swizzling) and change the header bytes from RIFF to RIFX. It's not guaranteed the WAV player will recognize the difference but give it a try.

Comment: If that doesn't work then do the swizzling when writing the WAV, and then swizzle the bytes back before passing to the MP3 encoder.

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to create the wav with Little endian byte order using ByteBuffer and ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN

Answer (score 2):

Here, this is my code, which work for me (record raw pcm audio and save it, play it afterwards with audiotrack):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    AudioRecord record = null;
    AudioTrack track = null;

    boolean isRecording;
    int sampleRate = 44100;

    Button startRecord, stopRecord, playRecord = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        startRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_recording);
        stopRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_recording);
        playRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_recording);
        startRecord.setOnClickListener(new StartRecordListener());
        stopRecord.setOnClickListener(new StopRecordListener());
        playRecord.setOnClickListener(new PlayRecordListener());

        stopRecord.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void startRecord()
    {
        File recordFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Record.pcm");
        try
        {
            recordFile.createNewFile();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(recordFile);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

            int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                     minBufferSize);
            record.startRecording();

            while (isRecording)
            {
                int numberOfShort = record.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++)
                {
                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                }
            }
            record.stop();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void playRecord()
    {
        File recordFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Record.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int) (recordFile.length() / shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];
        try
        {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(recordFile);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while (dataInputStream.available() > 0)
            {
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                   bufferSizeInBytes, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            track.play();
            track.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public class StartRecordListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    isRecording = true;
                    MainActivity.this.startRecord();
                }
            });
            recordThread.start();
            startRecord.setEnabled(false);
            stopRecord.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public class StopRecordListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            isRecording = false;
            startRecord.setEnabled(true);
            stopRecord.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public class PlayRecordListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            MainActivity.this.playRecord();
        }
    }
}
```

XML layout contains 3 buttons with the following ids: start_recording, stop_recording, play_recording

And add to following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Good luck and I hope it's okay for you, that I'm using 3 buttons in the code above.

Comment: Thank you, however I would like to avoid modifying my code as using MediaPlayer is fully implemented, but will consider this.